# Resume Back Kivy Application even if minimized (not closed) to recent activity

Tags: android, linux, python-2.7, kivy

is there a way to resume back a Kivy application to most recent activity even if minimized? i mean when i am in the application ( a compiled application as .apk) and i want to open wifi for example or check other apps, my application closes and i need to restart it again by pressing on it again...so if i am in the middle of an operation in my application (a calculation or an e-mail composition) and i want to check another application ,all my operation would be cancelled if i do so and of course it is a terrible user experience...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#pause-mode) describes how to enable pause mode, such that your app will be resumed rather than restarted if you leave then open it again.

The main point is to add an `on_pause` method to your `App` class, and have it return `True`.

Note that you are *never* guaranteed to be able to unpause again (Android itself may kill paused apps if their memory is needed etc.), so you should also use this method to carry out any state saving you need. However, it's unlikely to be a problem for short task switches, and may rarely or never come up in newer devices with more resources.

Comment: thank you @iclement it works just fine :  in the class MyApp(App): def on_pause(self): return True ,  def on_resume(self):pass...this i s cool!